# When call WaveExtensionMethods?

Tags: c#, naudio

Tell me how the compiler determines that it is necessary to apply the methods WaveExtensionMethods? How to find the description in the help?
In NAudioDemo.AudioPlaybackDemo: waveOut.Init (sampleProvider);
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to include the NAudio.Wave namespace, and they will be available (assuming you are using the latest beta of NAudio 1.7 - these methods aren't part of a released version yet).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I understand that. But why does it work? Where can I read about the mechanism?

Comment: Extension methods were a new feature in .NET 3.5. Any book on C# should explain how they work. Here's a blog post from Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoExtensionMethodsWorkAndWhyWasANewCLRNotRequired.aspx